# Trailing const& or && on function declaration

Tags: c++, c++11

I was looking at the API for `std::optional<T>` on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value_or). I was curious how `value_or` would work. Looking there, it seems there are two overloads:

```
template< class U > 
constexpr T value_or( U&& value ) const&;

template< class U > 
T value_or( U&& value ) &&;
```

What are the `const&` and `&&` trailing the function declaration? What is the difference between declaring a function as `const` and declaring it as `const&`?

Comment: This is actually a C++11 feature that compilers have recently gained support for.

Comment: @chris Cheers. I knew of rvalue references to *this, but since it's probably one of the last features to be implemented, I hadn't bothered looking into them at all.

Comment: @chris honestly I'd been waiting to answer this question I saw the answer in c++ primer a while ago, too bad I never realized it was a dupe :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An ampresand after the function means that `this` must be an lvalue, conversely the double ampersand means it must be an rval, the const just says that it's a nonmodifiable lval or rval

So a function qualified with `&` only works on a modifiable lval and if qualified with `&&` only works on an rval. I guess a `const &&` really makes no sense since a `const &` can bind to a temporary so the const qualifier only does anything for the lval.